# Output part of each line to a separate file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
a   AGTACTTCCAGGAACGGTGCACTCTCC
b   ATGGATTTTTGGAGCAGGGAGATGGAATAGGAGCATGCTCCAT
c   ATATTAAATGGATTTTTGGAGCAGGGAGATGGAATAGGAGCATGCTCCATCCACTCCACAC
d   ATCAGTTTAATATCTGATACGTCCTCTATCCGAGGACAATATATTAAATGGA
e   TTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTGTTCTTATAAGTTTAATATCTGATATGTCCTCTATCTGA
```

I want to make file `a.seq` which contains sequence `AGTACTTCCAGGAACGGTGCACTCTCC`.
Similarly `b.seq` contains `ATGGATTTTTGGAGCAGGGAGATGGAATAGGAGCATGCTCCAT`. In short, Column1 should be used as output file name with extension `.seq` and then it should have corresponding column2 sequence in it. I can do this by writing a perl script but anything on command line will be helpful. Hope to hear soon.

Answer (score 16):

My snap response would have been `awk` but if you're processing lots of lines —and I'm talking about millions— you'll likely see a real benefit from switching to a "real" programming language.

With that in mind (and `awk` already being taken as an answer) I wrote a few implementations in different languages and benchmarked them on the same 10,000-line  dataset on a PCI-E SSD.

```
me* (C)                0m1.734s
me (C++)               0m1.991s
me (Python/Pypy)       0m2.390s
me (perl)              0m3.024s
Thor+Glenn (sed|sh)    0m3.353s
me (python)            0m3.359s
jasonwryan+Thor (awk)  0m3.779s
rush (while read)      0m6.011s
Thor (sed)             1m30.947s
me (parallel)          4m9.429s
```

At a glance the C looks best but it was a pig to get to run that fast. Pypy and C++ are much easier to write and perform *well enough* unless you're talking about many billions of lines. If that were the case, an upgrade to doing this all in RAM or on an SSD might be a better investment than a code improvement.

Obviously in the time I've spent going through these you could probably have processed a few hundred million records *in the slowest option*. If you can only write `awk` or Bash loops, do that and get on with life. I clearly had too much spare time today.

I did also test some multi-threaded options (in C++ and Python and hybrids with GNU `parallel`) but the overhead of threads completely outweighs any benefit for such a simple operation (string splitting, writing).

#### Perl

`awk` (`gawk` here) would honestly be my first port of call for testing data like this but you can do fairly similar things in Perl. Similar syntax but with a slightly better writing handle.

```
perl -ane 'open(my $fh, ">", $F[0].".seq"); print $fh $F[1]; close $fh;' infile
```

#### Python

I *like* Python. It's my day job language and it's just a nice, solid and incredibly readable language. Even a beginner could probably guess what's happening here.

```
with open("infile", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        id, chunk = line.split()
        with open(id + ".seq", "w") as fw:
            fw.write(chunk)
```

You have to remember that your distribution's `python` binary isn't the only implementation of Python out there. **When I ran this same test through Pypy, [it was faster than C](http://thepcspy.com/read/python-isnt-slower-than-c/)** without any further logic optimisation. Keep that in mind before writing Python off as a "slow language".

#### C

I started this example to see what we could really get my CPU to do but frankly, C is a nightmare to code if you haven't touched it in a long time. This has the added downside of being limited to 100-char lines though it's very simple to expand that, I just didn't need it.

My original version was slower than C++ and pypy but [after blogging about it](http://thepcspy.com/read/python-isnt-slower-than-c/) I got [some help from Julian Klode](https://gist.github.com/julian-klode/4a7611b0f7fa7c4dfa0e). This version is now the fastest because of its tweaked IO buffers. It's also a *lot* longer and more involved than anything else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFLEN (8 * 1024)

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fpout;

    char line[100];
    char *id;
    char *token;
    char *buf = malloc(BUFLEN);

    fp = fopen("infile", "r");

    setvbuf ( fp , buf , _IOLBF, BUFLEN );
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL) {
        id = strtok(line, "\t");
        token = strtok(NULL, "\t");

        char *fnout = malloc(strlen(id)+5);
        fnout = strcat(fnout, id);
        fnout = strcat(fnout, ".seq");

        fpout = fopen(fnout, "w");
        setvbuf ( fpout , NULL , _IONBF , 0 );
        fprintf(fpout, "%s", token);
        fclose(fpout);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

#### C++

Performs well and is *much* easier to write than real C. You have all sorts of things that hold your hand (especially when it comes to strings and input). All that means you can actually simplify the logic down. `strtok` in C is a hog because it processes the entire string and then we need to do all that tiresome memory allocation. This just flits along the line until it hits the tab and we pull the segments out as we need them.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    ifstream in("infile");
    ofstream out;
    string line;

    while(getline(in, line)) {
        string::size_type tab = line.find('\t', 0);
        string filename = line.substr(0, tab) + ".seq";
        out.open(filename.c_str());
        out << line.substr(tab + 1);
        out.close();
    }

    in.close();
}
```

#### GNU Parallel

(Not the moreutils version). It's a nice concise syntax but OMGSLOW. I might be using it wrong.

```
parallel --colsep '\t' echo {2} \> {1}.seq <infile
```

#### Test harness generator

Here's my data-generator for 100000 lines of [ATGC]*64. It's not fast and improvements are very welcome.

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'ATGC' | fold -w 64 | awk 'NR>100000{exit}{printf NR"\t"$0"\n"}' > infile
```

Comment: I should point out that enumerating *all* your options for performance can be as wasteful as just going with the first thing that springs to mind. `awk` is still a fine answer for anything less than tens of millions. Even if you [linearly] scale this up to a billion lines, C is only saving you 1.5 hours over Perl and 3.6 hours over awk.

Comment: Now my C++ version is on there is *so* much faster, maybe I'd consider C++ for more simple text processing of huge data-sets. It's almost twice as fast and that's *many* hours difference when you get to billions of lines.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1445/

Comment: also: [Parkinson's law of triviality](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html)

Comment: Does your file gen sequence truly match the question? It doesn't seem to me that there is any indication that every line will be unique - as it seems your file gen assumes - but instead that it will be matched with an output filename at the head of the line. The `a,b,c,d,e` sequence in the question indicates even that there can be only as many as 26 unique lines in the file, but maybe that reads too much into it...

Comment: Only one of your solutions use multiple cores: GNU Parallel. Unfortunately you use it for what it is bad for: tiny jobs where speed is of the essence. Now if you instead combine it with one of your other solutions you will have a winner. parallel --pipepart -a input.seq --block 10m yourprogram (assuming input.seq is 10 GB and you have around 10 cpus). Here I will be surprised if I/O is not the limiting factor.

Comment: I think the generation speed of your test harness is bound by the random number generator. You can make it faster by using every number it gives or  generate an homogeneous distribution, e.g.: `paste <(yes A) <(yes T) <(yes G) <(yes C) | head -n1600000 | tr '\t' '\n' | shuf | tr -d \\n | fold -w64 | cat -n > infile`.

Comment: @OleTange Sure. If you're actually *doing something* (which we aren't here), multi-threading with something like Python 3.4+'s `asyncio` is likely going to be the happy spot between performance, power and —importantly— ease of development. GNU `parallel` is fun but forking out proper is mega-super-expensive. A worker thread pool is much better.

Comment: @Thor I feel like that guarantees an almost equal distribution of letters which probably isn't representative of a random sample, but it's certainly faster. I'd improve it further by changing the start: `yes "A T G C " | ... | tr ' ' '\n' | ...` or even something like: `printf 'A\0T\0G\0C\0%.0s' {1..160000} | shuf -z | fold -w64`

Comment: That is much better. I get a 2 times speedup with this version: `yes ATGC | fold -w1 | head -n6400000 | shuf | tr -d \\n | fold -w64`.

Answer (score 13):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s\n", $2>$1".seq"}' file
```

From the nominated `file`, print the second field in each record (`$2`) to a file named after the first field (`$1`) with `.seq` appended to the name.

As [Thor points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167639/output-each-line-to-a-file#comment276024_167641) in the comments, for a large dataset, you may exhaust the file descriptors, so it would be wise to [close each file after writing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html):

```
awk '{printf "%s\n", $2>$1".seq"; close($1".seq")}' file
```

Comment: Hi This works Thanks a lot..
Can you explain the code a bit?

Comment: @user3138373 Hope that helps...

Comment: It helps.. Thanks
Why won't print work instead of printf??

Comment: @user3138373 Sure, `print` would work; but `printf` gives you more control (and you may want that).

Comment: If there are many lines, all available file descriptors will be used, so you should probably add a `close($1".seq")`.

Comment: @jasonwryan Print is always more suitable in cases where you are just printing fields.

Comment: @Thor, true. Some `awk` implementations like GNU's know how to work around that though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I see, and it has been there for a while. I did not know about this, thanks for telling me.

Comment: This is perfect.  For my own use requirements, I threw it in a script something like the following (from memory, might not be exact): `[ -r "$1" ] || exit 1; myfile="${1##*/}"; awk -v filename="${myfile%.txt}" -v mydir="/tmp/" '! ($0 in lineshandled) {printf "%s", filename > mydir $0 ; close( mydir $0 ) ; lineshandled[$0]}' "$1"`

Answer (score 13):

Pure shell implementation:

```
while read -r filename content ; do
    printf '%s\n' "$content" >> "${filename}.seq"
done < /source/file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way you could do it with GNU sed:

```
<infile sed -r 's:(\w+)\s+(\w+):echo \2 > \1.seq:e; d'
```

Or more efficiently, as suggested by *glenn jackman*:

```
<infile sed -r 's:(\w+)\s+(\w+):echo \2 > \1.seq:' | sh
```

Comment: While that is cool, it's quite inefficient, having to spawn an external command for every line. It would be a bit better having the sed output all the raw commands, and pipe the output into "sh"

Comment: @glennjackman: This was just an interesting alternative way of doing it. If the input is large, `awk` is probably the most efficient tool to use. You are of course right about not spawning `sh` for each line, I have added the pipe-option as an alternative.